# Merging tags based on two different complex tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

In the below two ASNInPO's po_nbr is same container_id under ASNInCtn is same and item_id under ASNInItem is different. In this case two ASNInPO's has to be merged and two ASNInCtn's has to be merged into one tag.
This is my Input:

```
     <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
 <ASNInDesc>
    <asn_nbr>ASN-1</asn_nbr>
    <ASNInPO>
      <po_nbr>PO-2</po_nbr>
      <ASNInCtn>
         <container_id>CONTAINER-2</container_id>
         <ASNInItem>
            <item_id>ITEM-2</item_id>
            <unit_qty>3</unit_qty>
         </ASNInItem>
      </ASNInCtn>
   </ASNInPO>
   <ASNInPO>
      <po_nbr>PO-2</po_nbr>
      <ASNInCtn>
         <container_id>CONTAINER-2</container_id>
         <ASNInItem>
            <item_id>ITEM-3</item_id>
            <unit_qty>3</unit_qty>
         </ASNInItem>
      </ASNInCtn>
   </ASNInPO>
  </ASNInDesc>
```

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
 <ASNInDesc>
    <asn_nbr>ASN-1</asn_nbr>
    <ASNInPO>
      <po_nbr>PO-2</po_nbr>
      <ASNInCtn>
         <container_id>CONTAINER-2</container_id>
         <ASNInItem>
            <item_id>ITEM-2</item_id>
            <unit_qty>3</unit_qty>
         </ASNInItem>
         <ASNInItem>
            <item_id>ITEM-3</item_id>
            <unit_qty>3</unit_qty>
         </ASNInItem>        
      </ASNInCtn>
   </ASNInPO>
 </ASNInDesc>
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with `xslt-1.0`, I'll post a XSLT
1.0 solution using the [**Muenchian grouping**](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) method. (Perhaps someone
else will contribute a XSLT 2.0 solution. It might be instructive to
compare them.)

Let's walk through the stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

#### Grouping 1: `ASNInPO` elements by `po_nbr`

Since we want to group `ASNInPO` elements by their `po_nbr`, let's
start by defining a [**key**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) which allows retrieving `ASNInPO`
elements by their `po_nbr` value.

```
  <xsl:key name="ASNInPO-by-po_nbr" 
           match="ASNInPO" use="po_nbr"/>
```

Then we'll write a template which matches an `ASNInDesc`. We'll make a
copy of the element, along with its `asn_nbr`. Now we want to group
the contained `ASNInPO` elements by their `po_nbr`. We do this by
applying templates to the *first* `ASNInPo` in each group:

```
  <xsl:template match="ASNInDesc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="asn_nbr"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ASNInPO[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('ASNInPO-by-po_nbr', 
                                                   po_nbr)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

#### Grouping 2: `ASNInCtn` elements by `container_id`

But before we go further, we'll need to define another key. It seems
like we need to group `ASNInCtn` elements by their `container_id` (see note below if this is not the case).

```
  <xsl:key name="ASNInCtn-by-container_id" 
           match="ASNInCtn" use="container_id"/>
```

We'll need that key in the following template which matches `ASNInPO`
elements. Remember that the elements we process here will be the first
ones of their group, since we selected only those in the
`xsl:apply-template` above.

This template is similar to the one we wrote above. We make copy of
the element itself along with its `po_nbr` and then again apply
templates to the first `ASNInCtn` elements grouped by their
`container_id`:

```
  <xsl:template match="ASNInPO">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="po_nbr"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ASNInPO-by-po_nbr', po_nbr)/
                                   ASNInCtn[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('ASNInCtn-by-container_id',
                                                   container_id)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Finally, we write the template which matches `ASNInCtn` elements. This
copies the element itself, and its `container_id` and then copies all
`ASNInItem` elements in the *same group*:

```
  <xsl:template match="ASNInCtn">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="container_id"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('ASNInCtn-by-container_id', 
                               container_id)/ASNInItem"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

And we're done.

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Note

The solution assumes that the `ASNInCtn` element with a given
`container_id` can only appear within `ASNInPO` elements with the same
`po_nbr`. If this is not the case, then you need to adjust the key for
`ASNInPO` objects to use a combination of `po_nbr` and `container_id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!:) It is working only when Container_id is not repeating as you have mentioned in the note,but in my case it repeats.All the possible scenarios are explained in the following link.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627209/grouping-the-nodes-at-three-levels-and-summing-one-node) Please help me.Thanks You